# Testing for Granger Causality

Tags: python, granger-causality, statsmodels

I have two time series (Stocks and GDP) that I want to check for **Granger causality**. After reading the literature and documentations of various statistics software documentations (py statsmodels), I'm a little puzzled: What are the necessary steps for conducting a Granger causality test?

1. First, I understand that the time series should be both
   **stationary** if we want to measure Granger causality. Here, the ADF test is a Unit root test that checks whether a time series is
   stationary or not. In my case, both time series are stationary at
   level.
2. Second, I should check for the **lag order** to determine the
   maximum lag length for the Granger causality analysis. I do that via
   *model.select_order(10)* in Python statmodels and check which lags are indicated, for example by AIC and BIC.
3. Now, how about **cointegration**?  How do I check for cointegration
   in IPython and how do I interpret the results? I read in the literature about the "order of integration", written like I(0),I(1),I(2). I do not really understand what it means and how to produce the measure.

Otherwise, I'm well informed about how to check Granger itself and how to interpret its results.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: **1.** No, not necessarily. See Dave Giles' [blog post](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) for an excellent overview.

Comment: My impression is that co-integration tests are necessary (as an alternative to Granger Causality test) when at least some of the series is non-stationary. And this is not the case here.

Answer (score 6):

Follow this procedure (Engle-Granger Test for Cointegration):

1) Test to see if your series are stationary using adfuller test (stock prices and GDP levels are usually not)

2) If they are not, difference them and see if the differenced series are now stationary (they usually are).

3) If they are, your ORIGINAL series are said to be each integrated (I did not say co-integrated) of order 1; concisely noted as I(1).

4) If they are not both I(1), you can say safely say that they can not be co-integrated of order 1.

5) If they are both I(1), run a simple OLS regression of one of the other.

6) Check the residual of the OLS for stationarity. If they are stationary, then your original series are co-integrated of order 1.

Shortcomings of this method: 1) It may matter which variable you regress on the other, 2) it works only when you have two variables.

For a better test, you can use Johansen's procedure (https://github.com/josef-pkt/statsmodels/commit/29f0aa27d284ac0026e90ff9d877f7920a2c6056)

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mapsa/seminario-doc-2014/blob/master/cointegration-example.ipynb.